# Can I leave Germany before the end of my 10 days of quarantine?

Tags: germany, covid-19, quarantine

I need to travel from my home in Switzerland to my partner's home in Germany.
I only have a few days to spend there and according to the current regulations I would have to spend 10 days in quarantine.

My question is, am I allowed to travel directly to my partner's home, spend a few days there without leaving the house, and then go straight back?

Thank you.

Edit: I would travel to Hessen

Comment: Does this help? https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/coronavirus

Comment: @stephanmg, if the answer is on that site, can you please get it out and write it as an answer here? Link only answers are no use and link only comments are no use either.

Comment: @willeke i will try

Comment: It looks as though some aspects of the rules are _Land_ specific so the OP may need to give more details.

Comment: I would argue that you are doing quarantine wrong when you share your time with a person that doesn't belong to your household.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. A good rule of thumb worldwide is: with self-isolation, you either have to isolate for a maximum duration (in this case 10 days), or for your whole visit if it's less than that. You won't be refused "premature exit" or refused entry on the basis of your visit being too short.